# Raspberry Pi (RaspBMC) cronjobs not working

Tags: settings, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

I have attempted adding cronjobs via SSH at /etc/crontab and also crontab -e.  Neither one seems to work at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate cron jobs in Raspbmc
Per default running cron jobs is deactivated in Raspbmc and there are two ways to activate them.
- In the Raspbmc GUI under Programs -> Raspbmc Settings -> System Configuration -> Service Management -> Cronjob Scheduler
- Via SSH/FTP by modifying sys.service.cron value to “true” the settings file under /home//.xbmc/userdata/addon_data/script.raspbmc.settings/settings.xml

Answer (score 3):

Since `xbmc` has been renamed to `kodi` (version 14.x), the new path is

```
/home/pi/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/script.raspbmc.settings/settings.xml
```

Comment: Any idea where it is with osmc? There's a file at `/home/osmc/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/script.module.osmcsetting.pi/settings.xml`, but nothing with `cron` in it.